# How to assign value to a struct like initializing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Assume I have a struct in C++11:

```
typedef struct
{
   int val1;
   int val2;
} Mystruct;
```

I can initialize it like this and it works:

```
Mystruct a = {1,2};
```

but how can I reassign values to it in the same way:

```
Mystruct a = {1,2};
...................
a = {3,4};  //this line doesn't work
```

Update 1:

this is the exact code I copied out from visual studio and also the only code i wrote:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

struct Mystruct
{
   int val1;
   int val2;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Mystruct a = {1,2};
a = {3,4};  //this line doesn't work

return 0;
}
```

the errors are:

error C2059: syntax error : '{' c:\workspace\trycplus\trycplus\trycplus.cpp

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\workspace\trycplus\trycplus\trycplus.cpp

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\workspace\trycplus\trycplus\trycplus.cpp

**Update 1:**

I updated my Visual Studio 2012 to Nov 2012 CTP, and also changed the Platform Toolset to
:

Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012), the assignment still doesn't work

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/qc5ecs), once I fix the typo and assembly the fragments into something compilable. What exactly goes wrong? Are you sure you're (a) enabling C++11 support if necessary, and (b) doing the assignment inside a function? Could you post a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Why use `typedef struct` if you are doing C++?

Comment: this is for the compatibility betwten c and C++. with that or without doesn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: @crashmstr, It can help avoid subtle naming bugs (see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20ea9e4226a9d8e) vs. [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffa5d91be475dc1a)), but not many people at all do it.

Comment: Uniform initialization is not yet available in VS2012 RTM.  First version that supports it is the November 2012 CTP (don't use it) and VS2013 RTM.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning from an initializer list works fine in C++11:

```
a = {3,4};
```

See [live demo here](http://ideone.com/VGGfMO).

As an aside, you don't need the cumbersone `typedef` syntax, and you need `struct` instead of `strut`:

```
struct Mystruct
{
   int val1;
   int val2;
};
```

Comment: Just `a = {3,4};` should also work. @Giswin, Which compiler? MSVC12 supports uniform initialization.

Comment: IIRC, if you have defined any constructors on `MyStruct` it won't work.

Comment: @Dan, It will if one of them takes two ints.

Comment: @Giswin, Then you'd have to use the 2012 CTP compiler or upgrade to 2013 in order to use this feature. The latter is preferable.

Comment: this definitely doesn't work in visual studio  c++. Maybe you are right chris.

Comment: after installed Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP. it is still not working. Probably visual studio 2013 supports this feature.

Answer (score -1):

If you are utilizing C++11, then you shouldn't need `#include "stdafx.h"` or `int t_main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`. t_main carries command-line arguments, which your program doesn't need.